# `open -a` results in an "Unable to find application" error on OS X

Tags: macos, terminal

I would like to create a shortcut in my `.profile` file in OS X Lion to launch the iWork program "Numbers".

The application is in:

```
/Applications/iWork '09/Numbers.app
```

I created this shortcut:

```
alias psd="open -a Adobe\ Photoshop\ CS3"
```

It works fine to open Photoshop. So I created:

```
alias num="open -a iWork\ \'09/Numbers"
```

When I type "num" I get an error:

> Unable to find application named 'iWork '09/Numbers'.

I don't think it's a problem of backslashes before the space or the quote because I have tried countless variations to no avail. I also tried adding ".app" to the application name, but got the same error message.

**How can I create this alias?**

Comment: Alternatively, if you know you're using the correct name (in my case one that used to work with `open -a AppName` but suddenly stopped), you may need to rebuild launchservices: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67141094/1588795

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that next time it comes up!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you considered the following?

```
open -a Numbers
```

Applications opened by `open` aren't opened relative to their path, but just according to their actual name, as identified in `Contents/Info.plist` in the `.app` file itself.

If you want to be sure, you can also use the Bundle Identifier with the `-b` option:

```
open -b com.apple.iTunes
```

Which can be found in the `Info.plist` file too:

[image]

Comment: You could also use an absolute path like `open "/Applications/iWork '09/Numbers.app/"`

Comment: I started with that, but I got an error message. After reading your post, I went back and tried again. This time I noticed that the problem came from an old Mac System file from the '90s called Numbers. Once I deleted it, everything was fine. Thanks for the useful information, too.

Comment: Year 2024, still observing this issue, even when opening app by bundle identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, `alias num='/Applications/iWork '09/Numbers.app/'` ? 
It works for me. Add this to your `./bashrc` and source it. Then you can just execute it by typing `num` 
Using absolute path every time can be tedious.